# How to modify my readFile function so it does not stop at first line (java)

Tags: java

the following code will only read the first line of a text file and it will stop there. I've been experimenting with loops but i cannot get it to successfully update the line until there are no more lines in the file. can anyone help? thanks

```
public void readFile(){

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test1.txt"));
        words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        int lineNum = 1; // we read first line in start

        // delimeters of line in this example only "space"
        char [] parse = {' '};
        String delims = new String(parse);

        String line = in.readLine();
        String [] lineWords = line.split(delims);

        // split the words and create word object

        for (int i = 0; i < lineWords.length; i++) {
            Word w = new Word(lineWords[i]); 
            words.add(w);                                      
        }
        lineNum++;    // pass the next line

        line = in.readLine();

        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Continue reading until you run out of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to keep reading until you run out of lines, at which time `BufferedReader` will return `null`

```
        char[] parse = {' '};
        String delims = new String(parse);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] lineWords = line.split(delims);

                // split the words and create word object
            for (int i = 0; i < lineWords.length; i++) {
                Word w = new Word(lineWords[i]);
                words.add(w);
            }
            lineNum++;    // pass the next line

        }
```

You should be managing your resources better, if you open it, you should make all reasonable attempts to close.  Currently, if your code fails for some reason, the `in.close` line will never be called.  Also, you shouldn't ignore exceptions

Luckily, in Java 8, this is easy to manage...

```
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test1.txt"))) {
        //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Take a closer look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [`BufferedReader` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), especially [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

You may also want to take a look at [`LineNumberReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
     //process line
}
```

This nested statement reads a line from the `BufferedReader` and stores it in `line`. At the end of the file, `readLine()` will return `null` and stop the loop.